# Android dynamic UI which depends from response

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface

I am creating on android shop app. In product info I want to display all info and product options. I get options from server response (option name, list of option variants and size). How do I generate dynamically UI to display several product options?

For example: if product is TV then options be like: screen size, color, etc.

Here is what I want to display:
[image]

Comment: Probably the best way is using a RecyclerView with custom item and using sub Recyclerviews to display all the option variants for each option.

Comment: Solved it by creating nested recyclerview and declared child recyclerview inside parent